# MIMEMultipart edit msg['To'] recipients

Tags: python, email, smtp

I have a loop that iterates through a list of addresses and sends mail to each.

```
def send_mail(self, user_name, smtp_host, smtp_user, smtp_pass, smtp_port):
    s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_host[0],smtp_port[0])
    s.login(smtp_user[0],smtp_pass[0]) 

    msg = MIMEMultipart()         
    msg.attach(MIMEText(self.message))
    msg['From'] = user_name[0]        
    msg['Subject'] = self.subject

    for f in self.attachment_list:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
        part.set_payload(open('temp/'+f,"rb").read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{0}"'.format(os.path.basename(f)))
        msg.attach(part)
    for i,address in enumerate(Sheet.email_list):
        print("Send email: " + address)           
        msg['To'] = address
        s.sendmail(smtp_user[0], address, msg.as_string())
    s.quit()    
    print("SMTP connection closed")
```

The code runs fine and sends an email to each address. However, when I view the email in Mail Application it lists: "To: " with each address. I intend for it to only list the recipient who is receiving the emails address. I played around with the code and I have determined that the issue is coming from msg['To']. I have tried to adjust it many ways, but I do not know how to make it send with only the one recipients address displayed.

[msg['To'] addresses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHrw3.png)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I needed to replace the To header with each iteration.

```
        if 'To' in msg:
            msg.replace_header('To', address)
        else:
            msg['To'] = address
```